# Calling GET ASP .NET core 2.1 Web API from Angular 6+ client application doesn't return any data

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-webapi

I have created a get web API that returns a single object.When I call that API by typing URL in the browser this displays data in the JSON format on browser window as expected.But when I call the same API from my angular application the data is undefined.Can someone help what is wrong with my code?

I have tried calling web API from my angular application that returns array of strings.I am not receiving even strings in my angular app.

app.component.html

```html
<div style="text-align:center" class="container mt-2">
    <button (click)="search()">test</button>
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let item of Candidate">
        <h1>{{item.Name}}</h1>
        </li>
    </ul>   
</div>
```

app.component.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CandidateServicesService } from './candidate-services.service';
import { Candidate } from './core/models/Candidate.mode';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-root',
 templateUrl: './app.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
    candidate: Candidate[];
    constructor(private service: CandidateServicesService) { }
    search():void {
        this.service.getCandidateByPosId(101)
        .subscribe((data) => {
                this.candidate = data;
        });
    }
}
```

candidate-services.services.ts

```js
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { Candidate } from "./core/models/Candidate.mode";
@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class CandidateServicesService {
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

  baseUrl: string = "http://localhost:44370/api/Candidate";

  getCandidateByPosId(posId: number): Observable<Candidate> {
    return this.httpClient.get<Candidate>(this.baseUrl + "/" + posId);
  }
}
```

candidate.mode.ts(Candidate model class)

```js
export class Candidate {
  candidateId: number;
  name: string;
  email: string;
  phone: string;
  skills: string;
}
```

asp .net core Web Api

//Displays "Unknown error"at angular side.

```cs
[HttpGet ("{id}")]
public IActionResult<Candidate> GetBestCandidate (int id) {
    Candidate candidate = new Candidate {
        CandidateId = 1, Name = "John Smith",
            Email = "John.smith@gmail.com",
            Phone = "987654321", Skills = "test"
    }
    return candidate;
}
```

Comment: getCandidateByPosId(posId: number) {
return this.httpClient.get(this.baseUrl + "/" + posId);
} try this.

Answer (score 0):

Returning something of type `ActionResult` (as is the case here), requires providing the correct status code with your data.

The most common status code you'll use is `200 OK` and `403 Unathorized` (possibly `404 Not found` too). While you're focused on the data for your client, the framework you're using (.NET Core), sees it as a secondary content, whereas the main part is clarity on how it went.

So, providing the data **and** explaining that the operation went as supposed to would be achieved by

```
public ActionResult(...)
{ ...
  return Ok(someData);
}
```

while telling that something went wrong will be done by

```
public ActionResult(...)
{ ...
  return NotFound(someData);
}
```

In the service of your component in Angular, you'll subscribe to the operation and receive two different objects depending on what outcome that has been reported.

```
...
this.httpClient.get(...)
  .subscribe(
    success => console.log(success),
    error => console.log(error)
  );
```

Also, to be perfectly sure, I'd break-point the controller process and see what's being returned to avoid stupid cases where the "error" is that you do everything right but the name of a customer actually is *null undefined* because of some test data jerking around.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may lie in that you enable `https` for you web api, so change your `baseUrl` with `https`:

```
baseUrl: string = "https://localhost:44370/api/Candidate";
```